# Selectively reformatting a file with spaces and \n

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have multiple files in the following format. This one has 3 sequences (number of sequences vary in all files, but always end in ".") with 40 positions each, as indicated by the numbers in the first line. From the beginning of the lines (except the first one) there are the names of the sequences:

```
3 40
00076284. ATGTCTGTGG TTCTTTAACC 
00892634. TTGTCTGAGG TTCGTAAACC 
00055673. TTGTCTGAGG TCCGTGAACC 

          GCCGGGAACA TCCGCAAAAA
          ACCGTGAAAC GGGGTGAACT
          TCCCCCGAAC TCCCTGAACG
```

I need to convert it to this format, where the sequences are continuous, with no spaces nor \n, and on a new line after their names.The only spaces that should remain are between the two numbers in the first line.

```
3 40
00076284. 
ATGTCTGTGGTTCTTTAACCGCCGGGAACATCCGCAAAAA
00892634. 
TTGTCTGAGGTTCGTAAACCACCGTGAAACGGGGTGAACT
00055673. 
TTGTCTGAGGTCCGTGAACCTCCCCCGAACTCCCTGAACG
```

Tried sed to delete spaces and \n's but don't know how to apply it after the first line and how to avoid making one huge line.

Thanks

Comment: What happens with the rest of the input? You have three lines there that go puff for no reason.

Comment: The last 3 lines merge with their corresponding sequences. For a reference, you can see that the first merged sequence ends in AAAAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shell script that may provide what you need:

```
head -1 input
awk '
NR == 1 {  sequences = $1 ; positions = $2 ; next }
{ 
  if ( $1 ~ /^[0-9]/ ) {
    sid = $1 ; $1 = "" ; sequence_name[ NR - 1 ] = sid 
    sequence[ NR - 1 ] = $0
  } else {
    sequence[ ( NR - 1 )  % ( sequences + 1 ) ]  = sequence[ (NR-1) % ( sequences + 1 ) ] " " $0
  }
}
END {
  for ( x = 1 ; x <= length( sequence_name ) ; x++ )
  {
    print sequence_name[x]
    print sequence[x]
  }
}' input | tr -d ' '
```

I added `head -1` to the top of the shell just to get the first line out of your file.  I couldn't output the first line within the awk script because of the pipe to `tr -d ' '`.

Comment: The only detail is that i need the first line to remain the same. Do you know how to do it? Other than that, great solution!

Comment: That's it. Thanks @Mark

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, but my output is longer since if I actually concat all the last "orphan" sequences I get a way longer line.

```
cat input.txt  | awk '/^[0-9]+ [0-9]+$/{printf("%s\n",$0); next} /[0-9]+[.]/{ printf("\n%s\n",$1);for(i=2; i<=NF;i++){printf("%s",$i)}; next} /^ */{ for(i=1; i<=NF;i++){printf("%s",$i)}; next;}'
3 40
```

Please try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the position of empty line and merge the lines before empty line with those after:

```
awk '
   NR==1{print;next}
   NR!=1 && !empty{arr[NR]=$1 "\n" $2 $3}
   /^$/{empty=NR-1;next}
   NR!=1 && empty{printf "%s%s%s\n", arr[NR-empty], $1, $2}
' file
```

My second solution without `awk`: Merge the file with itself using empty line as separator

```
cat >file <<EOF
3 40
00076284. ATGTCTGTGG TTCTTTAACC 
00892634. TTGTCTGAGG TTCGTAAACC 
00055673. TTGTCTGAGG TCCGTGAACC 

          GCCGGGAACA TCCGCAAAAA
          ACCGTGAAAC GGGGTGAACT
          TCCCCCGAAC TCCCTGAACG
EOF

head -n1 file
paste <(sed -n '1!{ /^$/q;p; }' file) <(sed -n '1!{ /^$/,//{/^$/!p}; }' file) |
sed 's/[[:space:]]//g; s/\./.\n/'
```

Will output:

```
3 40
00076284.
ATGTCTGTGGTTCTTTAACCGCCGGGAACATCCGCAAAAA
00892634.
TTGTCTGAGGTTCGTAAACCACCGTGAAACGGGGTGAACT
00055673.
TTGTCTGAGGTCCGTGAACCTCCCCCGAACTCCCTGAACG
```

:

- `head -n1 file` output first line
- `sed -n '1!{ /^$/q;p; }' file`

  - `1!` - don't output first line
  - `/^$/q` - quit when empty line
  - `p` print everything else
- `sed -n '1!{ /^$/,//{/^$/!p}; }' file`

  - `1!` - ignore first line
  - `/^$/,//` - from empty line until the end
  - `/^$/!p` - output if not an empty tline
- `paste <(..) <(...)` - merge the two seds with a tab
- `sed 's/[[:space:]]//g; s/\./.\n/`

  - `s/[[:space:]]//g;` remove all spaces
  - `s/\./.\n/` replace a comma with a comma and a newline.